# Is there a way to link to a section with special characters in markdown?

Tags: markdown

Given the following header `## Header in a markdown file`, it is possible to create a link to this header with `[Link to header](#header-in-a-markdown-file)`.

This works well, but is there a way to create a link to the `## Header (in markdown)` header or `## && operator` header?

I do not want to misc markdown and HTML, I want markdown only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing about the standard rules of Markdown will give a heading an ID you can link to automatically.

Either your (unspecified) Markdown to HTML converter has an extension which does that or you are doing some kind of post-processing to add the IDs to the HTML.

Either way, it probably is generating an ID and you just need to find out what it is.

- Convert your Markdown to HTML
- View the HTML source
- Look at the `id` attribute on the heading

Then you can type that into the URL for your link.

Odds are that it will just [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `(` and `)` characters.